Linear operators vs rectangular linear transformations
Whether the following explanation of linear operator vs rectangular linear transformation is fine or need further modification?
When we define a define a linear transformation from a vector space to itself (e.g., $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$), then T is known as a linear operator and operates in the vector space to introduce a possible decomposition via eigen-decomposition.
While we define a define a linear transformation from a vector space V to another W ($\neq$V vector (e.g., $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m, m\neq n$), then T is known as a rectangular linear transformation and best explained by four fundamental subspaces of the matrix of transformation & singular-value-decomposition.
So, we can say that eigen-pair (eigen-value, eigen-vector, and eigen-decomposition) structure of a linear operator is generalized to singular-pair (singular-value, singular-vector, and singular-value-decomposition in order to explain a linear transformation via two basic linear transformations, namely rotation and scaling.

It is not always possible to give an eigendecomposition of a square matrix (not all matrices are diagonalisable). This can fail for essentially two reasons:

The characteristic polynomial does not have enough roots. Of course there are always enough complex roots, but they may not be real. Thus the eigendecomposition may not exist over $\mathbb{R}$.
The geometric multiplicity of an eigenspace may not be equal to the algebraic multiplicity. When this happens we need to use Jordan blocks. This may happen even when working over the complex numbers. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector


I haven't use the word diagonalizability. Please see the example in the explicit answer.

A "diagonalisation" is another word for "eigendecomposition". So "diagonalisable" means "has an eigendecomposition". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix

First, it is not true in general, except in the case of real field of scalars i.e. $\mathbb{R}$.

An explicit answer to above question:
Consider a matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1   \end{array} \right)$.
Then we get the following eigen-pairs:
$\lambda_1 =1 \pm i, w_1=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} i \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)+i\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)$,
and
$\lambda_2 =2 \pm i, w_2=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1+i \\ 1 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)+i\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)$.
Now, we have the following eigen-matrix as:
$S=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.
and
$S^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$.
So, finally A can be decomposed as:
$A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$, where $\Lambda = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2   \end{array} \right)$.
A kind request to delete expert that please don't delete this answer, it may be helpful for someone. If there is any issue regarding $\Lambda$, please let me know, it is just dealing with matrix representation of complex eigen-values.

The decompostion $A = S\Lambda S^{-1}$ is not an eigendecomposition, since $\Lambda$ is not diagonal.

May you explain, why it is not an eigen-decomposition?

Because $\Lambda$ is not diagonal. It seems like you have tried to do some kind of diagonalisation in $(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})^{2\times 2}$ (where $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ is the complexification of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a & -b \ b & a\end{pmatrix}$). This does not work because $A\notin (\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})^{2\times 2}$. Thus $A$ has an eigendecomposition as an element of $\mathbb{C}^{4\times 4}$, but not in $\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ or in $(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C})^{2\times 2}$.

$\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.
